# IIS - Using HttpHandler for all files except for one

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config

I use a custom HttpHandler in .NET for all `*.html` files, however I want to create a single exception for the file `foo.html`, which should be handled as a static file on the hard drive.  I've tried:

```
  <httpHandlers>
     <remove verb="*" path="*.html" />
     <add verb="*" path="/foo.html" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add verb="*" path="*.html" validate="false" type="Imp.Handler" />
  </httpHandlers>
```

As well as:

```
  <httpHandlers>
     <remove verb="*" path="*.html" />
     <add verb="*" path="*.html" validate="false" type="Imp.Handler" />
     <add verb="*" path="/foo.html" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  </httpHandlers>
```

However, both will cause Imp.Handler to handle `foo.html` requests still.  What am I doing wrong?

IIS is running in Classic mode.

Answer (score 0):

may be this method can help you,move the files to the other folder and disable httphandler for this folder.

```
<location allowOverride="false" path="Static">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.htm"/>
        <!--<add verb="*" path="/foo.htm" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />-->
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</location>

<httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" path="*.html" validate="false" type="Imp.Handler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

i trying test this,the question is :

`if i remove HttpHandler for the "*.html" in the location element,and add a other httphandler will doesn't worked`.for example:

```
<location>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.htm"/>
    <add verb="*" path="foo.html" validate="false" type="Imp.Handler" />
</location>
```

Comment: No, I need the path to be `/foo.html`

Comment: ok,or you can use IIS's ISAPI to solve this.`Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter`